# How do I replace a bit of text with string variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

I know this is a really simple question, but I need to replace this bit of text in a paragraph with a variable every time an even fires.

The markup looks like this

```
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
#container {width:100%; text-align:center; }
#heading {width:100%; text-align:center; }
</style>
</head>

<div id="heading">
<h1>hello</h1> 
</div> 
<body>
<div id="container">
<textarea name="mytextarea" cols="60" rows="40"></textarea>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

What I need is where it says "hello" in the  tags, is for that to be a variable that van be replaced by a string that I will generate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One example on how can be simple things made complicated :)

javascript:

```js
// simple way:
function replace_text(text) {
    var heading = document.getElementById('heading');
    heading.innerHTML = '<h1>' + text + '</h1>';
}

// complicated way:
function replace_text2(text) {
    var heading = document.getElementById('heading');
    var node = heading.childNodes[0];
    while ( node && node.nodeType!=1 && node.tagName!='H1' ){
        //console.log(node.nodeType,node);
        node = node.nextSibling;
    }
    if (node) {
        node.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(text),node.childNodes[0]);
    }
}
```

html:

```html
<input type="button" onclick="replace_text('HELLO 1!');" value="Replace 1st text" />
<input type="button" onclick="replace_text2('HELLO 2!');" value="Replace 2nd text" />
```

[The script is here](http://pastebin.com/nCzV1gNi).

Answer (score 1):

You could create a function that looks something like this.

```
function replaceTitle (replaceText) {
    document.getElementById("heading").getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = replaceText;
}
```

If you are using **jQuery** it could look more like this.

```
function replaceTitle (replaceText) {
    $("#heading h1").html(replaceText);
}
```

Then you call the function like this

```
replaceText(yourVariable);
```

It would probably be better to give your `<h1>` tag an id or a class so you can reference it directly, but I am going to assume that you have good reason for not doing so.